# How to parse MKV file and stream it over RTP as H.264 encoded stream

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtp, mkv

Using gstreamer on Nvidia Jetson Nano, I want to read from MKV file and encode it as H264 to stream via RTP.
I successfully did it with MP4 file this way:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=$file | decodebin | videoconvert | omxh264enc | video/x-h264, width=1280, height=720, format=I420, stream-format=byte-stream | rtph264pay | udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

But when I wanted to parse MKV, I received errors, so I tried this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=$file | matroskademux| videoconvert | omxh264enc | video/x-h264, width=1280, height=720, format=I420, stream-format=byte-stream | rtph264pay | udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Then I received an error:

```
./grammar.y(510): gst_parse_no_more_pads ():
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:matroskademux0:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstMatroskaDemux named matroskademux0 to some pad of GstVideoConvert named videoconvert0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:matroskademux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
matroska-demux.c(5213): get_matroska_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:matroskademux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
```

I then tried removing the `videoconvert` pipe and go straight to encoding H264, but it didn't work also.

What is the correct approach pipelining it?